# Cast Class object to EditText in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-gui

```
public void changeCurrency(RelativeLayout layout) {
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
        Class c = v.getClass();
        if (c == EditText.class) {
            // validate EditClass
        } else if (c == TextView.class) {
            //validate RadioButton
        } 
    }
}
```

In the above code I'm trying to iterate through gui elements in a layout and validate their contents. I'm struggling at the commented parts.

I.e. getting access to the EditText's text value..

I can't figure out how to cast the c object to a EditText to check the values.

Ideas?

Comment: you mean a getText() ?

Comment: No, I can't call getText() on the c object because it's class hasn't been defined at that point and I'm trying to figure out how to cast it to an EditText.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the logic below

```
View v = layout.getChildAt(i);

if (v instanceof EditText) {
    EditText et = (EditText) v;

    //Do stuff

} else if (v instanceof TextView) {

    //Do other stuff

}
```

Since `EditText` is a subclass of `TextView`, you need to check for `EditText` first.  An `EditText` will test positive as an instance of `TextView`.

Comment: Thanks.. realised this myself after I kept trying to cast C instead of V for some reason.. It's late.. lol. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the views that use text extend from TextView. This should be sufficient if all you are doing is validating text.

```
public void changeCurrency(RelativeLayout layout) {
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof TextView) {
            TextView t = (TextView) v;
            String text = t.getText().toString();
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was about to answer the same thing. Kudos to this answer!!